# How do I make 2 images (same height different width) shrink proportionally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have the following design[image]

How do I keep these 2 images stay side by side and when the browser shrinks the two should shrink proportionally maintaining the proportion and height. Can't use bootstrap columns properly and display inline-block isn't working for me either. This is driving me crazy. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, the code was very simple. I thought it's not necessary.

Comment: SO isn't for people to write code for you. It's for you write code, and ask help when you are stuck with the code you wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a % `width` to each according to their ratio.

```css
img {
  padding: 1%;
  width: 64.3%;
}
img + img {
  width: 31.5%
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/940/400" /><img src="http://lorempixel.com/460/400" />
```

Comment: Thank you! I needed to tweak it a bit but you pointed me in the right direction. It wasn't hard but somehow I wasn't able to think straight and I'm on a deadline.

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/2028L68u/1/

CSS -

```
    img{
  display:inline-block;
}
#img1{
  width:67%;
  float:left;
}

#img2{
  width:33%;
  float:left;
}
```

HTML -

```
<img id="img1" src="http://www.sixdegreesdigitalmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Google-Tools-part-two-940x400.jpg" />
<img id=img2 src="http://kitengelaterraces.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Slider-460x400.jpg"/>
```